# sencha touch 2 list of albums with photo scrollable horizontally on the list

Tags: list, extjs, touch, carousel, xtype

Been searching for this but to no avail.
Let say I have a long list of albums and each album only have less than 5 photos. I want to show the photos directly on the list of albums. The photos can be scroll horizontally, eg similar to 00:52 of fastbook video on youtube.
I tried using carousel in the list, but it seems any declaration of items is not allowed in list xtype.
items:{
   xtype: list,
   items: {
      xtype: carousel
   }
}

Comment: Why do you want to use the list component for this? You could just programmatically build the necessary components underneath each other.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to make use of infinite list function of List and I feel the way fastbook do is the way i want to do it. I'm not looking to build the whole fastbook. I'm just looking to build the list of album where the photo can be scroll horizontal.
I tried exploring listitem and xtemplate to no avail too...